# Why CDN ASes are not shown in BGPreader?

Tags: bgp

I am using bgpreader as

```
bgpreader -A "20940" -w 2023-7-28,2023-7-31
```

where ASN 20940 is Akamai (a CDN). I wanted to view RIB, updates involving this ASN. I couldn't find the result for other CDN ASNs (eg. ASN 12200- Rackspace, 16509-Amazon). I can view results when I use any ASN instead of CDNs there.

Comment: I've never used this tool myself, but looking at the documentation I'd expect to use `-a` (matching origin ASN)  instead of `-A` (as-path).

Comment: No change even in using -a option.